Touhpad acting like a touchscreen with constant touch
I have connected an external keyboard with a touchpad via Bluetooth. The touchpad works like a touchscreen as every time I touch the left edge of the touchpad, there's a click at the left edge of the screen. Furthermore, the pointer is always in select mode, so if I move it, it tries to select everything in between. Here are the xinput settings:
Device 'SMARTDEVIL':
    Device Enabled (188):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (190): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (324):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (325):   0
    libinput Calibration Matrix (364):  1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Calibration Matrix Default (365):  1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (309): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (310):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (311):    0, 0
    Device Node (312):  "/dev/input/event16"
    Device Product ID (313):    1452, 591
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (340):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (341):   1
    libinput High Resolution Wheel Scroll Enabled (344):    1

And these are the libinput settings:
Device:           SMARTDEVIL
Kernel:           /dev/input/event16
Group:            12
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             101x69mm
Capabilities:     keyboard pointer touch 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      identity matrix
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Here's the udevadm info:
P: /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:05AC:024F.0007/input/input28/event15
N: input/event15
L: 0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:05AC:024F.0007/input/input28/event15
E: DEVNAME=/dev/input/event15
E: MAJOR=13
E: MINOR=79
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=12240226655
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN=1
E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
E: ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
E: ID_INPUT_WIDTH_MM=101
E: ID_INPUT_HEIGHT_MM=68
E: ID_BUS=bluetooth
E: XKBMODEL=pc105
E: XKBLAYOUT=us
E: BACKSPACE=guess
E: LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=5/5ac/24f:b0:68:e6:0b:a0:6e
E: TAGS=:power-switch:
E: CURRENT_TAGS=:power-switch:

I tried looking at debug events:
sudo libinput debug-events --device=/dev/input/event15 
-event15  DEVICE_ADDED            SMARTDEVIL                        seat0 default group1  cap:kp  size 101x69mm scroll-nat calib
 event15  POINTER_MOTION_ABSOLUTE +0.015s   38.59/ 99.89
 event15  POINTER_MOTION_ABSOLUTE +0.030s   38.84/ 99.89

